# Print items from list within a json object using Python using for each loop

Tags: python

I have a json object that contains a list. I am just simply trying to extract the top level element and the value inside a list and print it.

My json is as follows

```
{
  'apple': [1001, 1002], 
  'banana': [2001, 2002], 
  'figs': [3001]
}
```

I want to simply do something like:

for each fruit in this list, print the number.

E.g.

```
It is apple with code 1001

It is apple with code 1002

It is banana with code 2001

It is banana with code 2002

It is figs with code 3001
```

I have been trying to use this for each statement in Python but I can't seem to get the value within the list.

Thanks

Comment: What does your `for` statement look like? Please include the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it in this way:

```
obj = {
  'apple': [1001, 1002], 
  'banana': [2001, 2002], 
  'figs': [3001]
}

for i in obj.keys():
    for j in obj[i]:
        print("It is ",i," with code ",j)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your dictionary items and print each code in your array.

```
for fruit, codes in obj.items():
    for code in codes:
        print(f'It is {fruit} with code {code}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to first iterate over each item in the dictionary, and then within each item iterate over each value in the values_list.

For example:

```
json_data = {
    'apple': [1001, 1002],
    'banana': [2001, 2002],
    'figs': [3001]
}
for key, values_list in json_data.items():
    for value in values_list:
        print(f'It is {key} with code {value}')
```

p.s. Can you update the question with what the for each statement you tried looks like?